# Selenium [python] not clicking an <li> button

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

So I have been trying to use selenium to click an `<li>` button on an HTML which is in a `<ul>` tag and looks something like this:

```
...
 <ul id="ulVisualization">
     <li class="active" id="liMap">Map</li>
     <li id="liBar" class="">Bar</li>
     <li id="liLine">Line</li>
 </ul>
...
```

I have been using the following command to get to the element using XPATH:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//li[@id='liBar']"))).click()
```

Yet for some reason that I have not been able to identify, this command is not able to find/click that button and the command hits its time-out.
I have even tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="liBar"]').click()
```

But that too was of no avail, throwing an error message saying `NoSuchElementException: Message:`

I would appreciate any and all help and thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

Additionally, I have noticed that when I click on the button manually the HTML modifies to:

```
...
 <ul id="ulVisualization">
     <li class="" id="liMap">Map</li>
     <li id="liBar" class="Active">Bar</li>
     <li id="liLine">Line</li>
 </ul>
...
```

Revealing the data I am trying to acquire later in the HTML code, which was not available before I clicked the button manually.

Comment: Share the website also. And some elements are dynamically added after some actions. So you may be missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to click on the Element, try `element_to_be_clickable`, instead of `presence_of_element_located`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@id='liBar']"))).click()
```

Make sure the locator you are using is Unique, that is 1/1. [Link to Refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

And also check if the **Elements** are in an `iframe` or in an `shadow-root` or Trying to find Element in a `newly opened browser tab`.

If none of them work, apply some `time.sleep()` and check if it works.

Comment: The elements are in an `iFrame`, but using this didn't work either. I even tried putting `time.sleep(5)`, both before and after the search command but nothing. Gives a `TimeoutException: Message:`.

Comment: @VivaanGupta - If the elements are in an `iframe`, need to `switch to iframe` and then try to access the elements.

Comment: Links to refer - [Link1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/select-iframe-using-python-and-selenium) , [Link2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-frames-iframes-in-selenium-with-python/)